# Calculation of expectation of multivariate variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Let $x_i, i=1, ..., n$ be identically distributed $(m, p)$-multivariate random variables, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i=y$ and $y+x_n=m$. Let $k_i, i=1,..., n$ is in $N$ and such that $\sum_i{k_i}=K$.

Find 
$$
E\left[\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^{k_i}\right)(m-y)^{K-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}k_i}\right].
$$

I have been trying to open up brackets inside of the expectation, but the computations does not seems get easier.

Comment: But you haven't specified a distribution?

Comment: @joriki: thank you. I have corrected it.

Comment: I don't think you have. Perhaps you intend to imply some distribution by "$(m,p)-multivariate", but I'm not familiar with that terminology. I don't see anything else in the question that would imply a distribution. Or do you want to calculate the expectation in terms of the (unknown) expectations of the individual variables?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get it in terms of the unknown expectations of the individual variables. I have also tried nested expectations, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly weird exercise; there's just a bit of algebraic unpacking to do, without any probabilistic content.

With $\sum_ik_i=K$, the exponent is $K-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}k_i=k_n$. With $y+x_n=m$, the base is $m-y=x_n$. So the last factor is just the factor $x_n^{k_n}$ that’s missing in the product, so the whole thing is just

$$
E\left[\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{k_i}\right]\;,
$$

which would have been

$$
\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[x_i^{k_i}\right]
$$

if you hadn’t removed the independence assumption. I don’t think there’s more to say about it than that without knowing anything about the distribution.